# Material UI Autocomplete Full Width

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have an `Autocomplete` element in `Material UI` but the drop-down isn't taking the full width of the `TextField`.

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you tell us which version of Material UI..?

Comment: I'm using MUI 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quickest way to achieve this is to add new props to the autocomplete element called `style` (version 4) or `sx` (version 5). The following examples show how to do this:

```
    <Autocomplete
      (...)
      style={{ width: 300 }}
    />
```

```
    <Autocomplete
      (...)
      sx={{ width: 300 }}
    />
```

or percentage value

```
    <Autocomplete
      (...)
      style={{ width: "100%" }}
    />
```

```
    <Autocomplete
      (...)
      sx={{ width: "100%" }}
    />
```

If this is not working then please show us what CSS rules are applied to class called `searchContainer`.